# AttributeError: module 'mmap' has no attribute 'PROT_READ' при вызове python через командную строку cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Установил с офф сайта python  версии 3.8.5.
Хотя везде написано, что выше версии python 3.4, pip отдельно устанавливать не надо, но у меня при вводе команды `pip --version` или `pip install pip` появляется ошибка `AttributeError: module 'mmap' has no attribute 'PROT_READ'`
Она же появляется всегда, когда я пытаюсь вызвать через python любую команду например `python get-pip.py`
Никакой информации в инэте найти не смог, к сожалению. Не понимаю с чего даже начинать.
Путь к пайтону в переменных среды (`PATH`)прописан. На компе установлена только одна версия python (команда `python --version` возвращает версию 3.8.5)
Pycharm к примеру у меня работает, но я хотел бы поставить django, а через pycharm он не запускается - пишет, что возможно у меня не установлена виртуальная среда. Вот я и решил установить его через cmd.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Попробуй удалить 3.8.5 и поставить 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Может быть кому-то будет полезно. Мне подсказали решение:

- Необходимо удалить python.
- Проверить не осталась ли случайно папка с    python после его
  деинсталяции. (У меня как раз осталась)
- Если осталась, удалить её руками. Убрать её из `path`.
- Поставить python x64 (не знаю, м.б. и x86 бы сработала, но советовали
  именно 64-битную)

Готово.